# Spring roo and iText PDF unsure how to install?

Tags: java, spring-roo

I've got a spring roo project and I would like to have the ability of allowing a user to be able to download a pdf from my project. I know how to generate the PDF but I'm not entirely sure about how to install iText 5.1.2 into my spring Roo project.

Comment: How is your project setup? Is it maven based? Is it just a default project generated by your IDE?

Comment: @micfra it is maven based, atm i am only using the spring roo shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add iText to your Maven project, just add the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>  
  </dependency>

  <!-- other dependency -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: does it matter where i have the itextpdf jar? its currently in /home/user

Comment: Maven will download all jars for you. It will be downloaded to `~/.m2/repository/<groupId>/<atifactId>/atifactId.jar` if not specified otherwise. You should rund `mvn install` before running any roo stuff. This may help.